# Interactive Brokers Python API ERROR -1 322 Processing request

Tags: python, api, tws

I am trying to cancel all orders but receive this error message

openOrder id: 62 ES FUT @ GLOBEX : BUY STP 13.0 PreSubmitted
orderStatus - orderid: 62 status: PreSubmitted filled 0.0 remaining 13.0 lastFillPrice 0.0

openOrder id: 63 ES FUT @ GLOBEX : BUY LMT 13.0 PreSubmitted
orderStatus - orderid: 63 status: PreSubmitted filled 0.0 remaining 13.0 lastFillPrice 0.0

openOrder id: 61 ES FUT @ GLOBEX : SELL STP LMT 13.0 Submitted
orderStatus - orderid: 61 status: Submitted filled 0.0 remaining 13.0 lastFillPrice 0.0

ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture

ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds

ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil

ERROR -1 322 Error processing request:-'bt' : cause - jextend.bt.l(bt.java:59)

unhandled exception in EReader thread

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
                    posns = []
                    fname = 'OpenPos.txt'
                    def __init__(self):
                        EClient.__init__(self, self)
                    
                    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
                        super().nextValidId(orderId)
                        self.nextorderId = orderId
                        

                    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFullPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
                        print('orderStatus - orderid:', orderId, 'status:', status, 'filled', filled, 'remaining', remaining, 'lastFillPrice', lastFillPrice)
    
                    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
                        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

                    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
                        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId, execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)
                      
                def run_loop():
                    app.run()
                    
                app = IBapi()
                app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
                time.sleep(2)
                
                app.nextorderId = None
                api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
                api_thread.start()
                app.reqGlobalCancel()
                time.sleep(3)
                done=True
                time.sleep(1)
                app.disconnect()
```

Comment: Not sure what this means exactly......The "322" error would occur if you query historical data and use the same tickerId to query another historical data request at the same time. Though tickerId's can be re-used, it is crucial to ensure an existing request is completed before using the same tickerId value. Alternatively, you can specify a unique tickerId for each request. Please review the historical data requests to review how your program is using the Id values.

Comment: `322 Server error when processing an API client request`  Show the trace, what happened is you had an error somewhere so it disconnects.   My guess is the unconventional threading.  The api is meant to be asynchronous, never use sleep.

Comment: Great guess! Thank you!

Comment: @brian, thanks, I have a similar issue with an app that was working and is now showing that error (using ib_insync, Win10,Pyt3.7 or 3.9, Java 1.8)